# Rails 5 - helper renders form multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5 app I follow Ryan Bates' #196 for nested forms on 3 parent objects. When using his application helper (below) it returns 3 new fieldsets. Why / where is the loop over the association? How can I get it to only render the form once?

Thanks!

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.simple_fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |f|
        render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: f)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior occurs due to adding the related coffee script to all coffee files. It gets then added to `application.js` for each `js.coffee` file.